# R: Using mapply with additional lists as arguments

Tags: r, mapply

I have the following list and vectors of parameters:

```
myList <- list(c(3, 0, 1), c(2, 2, 2))
vPar1 <- c(1, 5, 100)
vPar2 <- c(100, 5, 1)
```

and I'm trying to draw samples from 3 `Beta` distributions with shape parameters `shape1 = vPar1` and `shape2 = vPar2` (element-wise).

The expected result would be a list with two elements: the first element would consist of 4 random numbers (3 from a `Beta(1, 100)` and 1 from a `Beta(100, 1)` distribution) whereas the second list element would consist of a total of 6 random numbers (2 random numbers of a  `Beta(1, 100)`, `Beta(5, 5)` and `Beta(100, 1)` distributions each).

I tried to produce the required result using `mapply` i.e. cycling through the elements of the 3 arguments, but I can't figure how it should be used exactly:

```
mapply(function(x, shape1, shape2) {unlist(rbeta(x, shape1, shape2))}, 
          myList, 
          MoreArgs = list(shape1 = vPar1, shape2 = vPar2), 
          SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

This results in a list of two elements but with 3 random numbers each, insetad of the expected 4 and 6 numbers respectively. I'd be grateful for any suggestions! Thanks.

Comment: From the help:  `n 
number of observations. If length(n) > 1, the length is taken to be the number required.` So the actual values in your myList vectors are being ignored. Their length , 3, is being used

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to loop over the `list` with `lapply` and then apply the 'vPar1' and 'vPar2' as arguments in a nested `Map` within the `lapply`

```
lapply(myList, function(x) unlist(Map(rbeta, n = x, shape1 = vPar1, shape2 = vPar2)))
#[[1]]
#[1] 0.031955823 0.001533638 0.012877288 0.998004973

#[[2]]
#[1] 0.021860350 0.002145949 0.514477229 0.479578366 0.996876238 0.992356962
```

---

It can also be written as

```
lapply(Map(Vectorize(rbeta), myList, MoreArgs = list(shape1 = vPar1, 
        shape2 = vPar2)), unlist)
```

Comment: That is absolutely brilliant! You will not believe how long I spent (in vain) trying to figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity, I wanted to see if you could do this without nested  `lapply`/`Map`. I don't think there's any benefit to doing it this way, but here it is. Use `Vectorize` so you don't have to use `Map` inside `lapply` (well, don't have to type it out at least), then use `compose` so you don't have to do another `lapply` pass to unlist.

```
set.seed(1)
lapply(myList, purrr::compose(unlist, Vectorize(rbeta, SIMP = F)), 
       shape1 = vPar1, shape2 = vPar2)

# [[1]]
# [1] 0.0269188825 0.0074012868 0.0005853054 0.9941391825
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 0.037118765 0.004534898 0.631806102 0.602790723 0.983948500 0.999301928
```